# TL-WN725N (v2.2) driver doesn't work

Tags: drivers, usb

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a 64 bit computer and I am trying for days to run the driver for the Wlan USB adapter TL-WN725N (v2.2). Just switched to Linux so I am a total Newbie.

I used a lot of instructions which I found on the internet (like [this](//forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/problem-mit-usb-adapter-tp-link-tl-wn725n-v2/#post-5536902) or [this](http://brilliantlyeasy.com/ubuntu-linux-tl-wn725n-tp-link-version-2-wifi-driver-install/)) but non of them worked. I really can't figure out what the problem is.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0181 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.   
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for 
Bluetooth   
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub>
```

`modprobe 8188eu`:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8188eu': Operation not permitted
```

When I try [this solution](/questions/678134/how-to-install-tp-link-wn725n-wifi-usb-adapter-on-ubuntu-ubuntu-14-04-3-lts) it tells me:

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
fatal: Zielpfad 'rtl8188eu' existiert bereits und ist kein leeres Verzeichnis.
```

(its german, in english its: destination path 'rtl8188eu'already exists and is no empty directory)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `sudo modprobe 8188eu`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: I tried but failed

Comment: @Henner Try my answer, please tell me if you succeed. I'm waiting in case you need help.

Comment: Git's error message is actually quite specific about the issue. Just (re-)move the existing non-empty existing directory `rtl8188eu`. By the way, you can make most programs print English messages by prefixing the command with `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX`, e. g. `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX free`. Works the same for graphical applications. With super-user privileges you need `sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX apt ...` or `gksudo env LC_MESSAGES=POSIX synaptic` (for graphical applications).

Answer (score 1):

You can install the driver this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

You need to disable Secure Boot if you are using UEFI.

Comment: You made my day!
After hours of trying it finally works.
Thanks a lot and have a nice day =)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the driver [from here](http://www.tp-link.com/il/download/TL-WN725N.html#Driver). Choose the driver for linux. Install the driver by changing your directory to the `driver` and then typing the following commands

`sudo make`

`sudo make install`.

Detailed installation instructions are given in the zip file ( which has to be extracted first).

Comment: Ask, if there is anything you didn't understand.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, but when I download the zip file and try to unpack it it tells me "while unpacking an error aocured"

Comment: Mine worked fine. Is the zip file 2.6MB in size?

Comment: I'll send you the extraction of the zip file via mail or something if possible.

Comment: the size of the file is 2.45MB.  henna-p@web.de
thanks a lot

Comment: The one I downloaded was 2.6MB. I guess you are downloading the wrong file. I'll send you the zip and the extracted file via mail but try the zip file first. If, it doesn't work then go for the extracted ones.

Comment: I sent you the mail.

Comment: Is your problem fixed?

Comment: This driver will not build for 16.04. I patched it and placed to a PPA.

Comment: thanks @ Emad Arshad Alam for the driver via email. for any reason I could also not unpack the zip. but finally pilot 6 instruction worked out well.
lets see if i can figure out what the problem is with the unzipping

thanks to everybody helping me