# TL-WN725N Wifi adapter not getting detected on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, tp-link

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0c45:649a Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Followed Step given on below provided link:- http://brilliantlyeasy.com/ubuntu-linux-tl-wn725n-tp-link-version-2-wifi-driver-install/

Also, I am using an ethernet adapter too which is working fine.Please provide a solution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6- check now

Comment: Why don't you post is text?

Comment: `0bda:8152` is a USB Ethernet adapter, not a wireless. Is the wn725N inserted?

Comment: I am using an ethernet adapter too which is working fine. Chek the output of lsusb after inserting wireless usb adapter

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/833886/tl-wn725n-v2-2-driver-doesnt-work